# Changing correlation matrix into covariane matrix Matlab

Tags: matlab, correlation, covariance

I'm trying to change a correlation matrix into co-variance matrix...

Importing some data, I found the co-variance  (sigma_a)

```
sigma_a = (sigma_d + (mu_d'+1)*(mu_d+1)).^N - (mu_d'+1).^N *(mu_d+1).^N;
```

Which returns...

```
0.1211    0.0231    0.0422    0.0278    0.0411    0.0354    0.0289    0.0366    0.0343    0.0165
0.0231    0.0788    0.0283    0.0242    0.0199    0.0248    0.0219    0.0199    0.0253    0.0140
0.0422    0.0283    0.1282    0.0339    0.0432    0.0366    0.0321    0.0399    0.0420    0.0216
0.0278    0.0242    0.0339    0.0554    0.0261    0.0294    0.0312    0.0269    0.0297    0.0164
0.0411    0.0199    0.0432    0.0261    0.0849    0.0289    0.0271    0.0371    0.0317    0.0173
0.0354    0.0248    0.0366    0.0294    0.0289    0.0728    0.0293    0.0400    0.0339    0.0149
0.0289    0.0219    0.0321    0.0312    0.0271    0.0293    0.0454    0.0276    0.0309    0.0135
0.0366    0.0199    0.0399    0.0269    0.0371    0.0400    0.0276    0.0726    0.0356    0.0162
0.0343    0.0253    0.0420    0.0297    0.0317    0.0339    0.0309    0.0356    0.0715    0.0198
0.0165    0.0140    0.0216    0.0164    0.0173    0.0149    0.0135    0.0162    0.0198    0.0927
```

Then I found  the correlation matrix (rho)

```
rho = inv(sqrt(diag(diag(sigma_a))))*sigma_a*inv(sqrt(diag(diag(sigma_a))));
```

Which returns...

```
  1.0000    0.2365    0.3388    0.3396    0.4050    0.3772    0.3897    0.3899    0.3686    0.1556
  0.2365    1.0000    0.2812    0.3656    0.2437    0.3274    0.3658    0.2631    0.3377    0.1638
  0.3388    0.2812    1.0000    0.4027    0.4141    0.3792    0.4199    0.4133    0.4382    0.1985
  0.3396    0.3656    0.4027    1.0000    0.3809    0.4638    0.6221    0.4246    0.4728    0.2295
  0.4050    0.2437    0.4141    0.3809    1.0000    0.3681    0.4366    0.4732    0.4068    0.1948
  0.3772    0.3274    0.3792    0.4638    0.3681    1.0000    0.5093    0.5499    0.4707    0.1813
  0.3897    0.3658    0.4199    0.6221    0.4366    0.5093    1.0000    0.4797    0.5428    0.2079
  0.3899    0.2631    0.4133    0.4246    0.4732    0.5499    0.4797    1.0000    0.4936    0.1971
  0.3686    0.3377    0.4382    0.4728    0.4068    0.4707    0.5428    0.4936    1.0000    0.2435
  0.1556    0.1638    0.1985    0.2295    0.1948    0.1813    0.2079    0.1971    0.2435    1.0000
```

I know there is the function corrcov() in matlab that finds the correlation matrix... So I tried,

```
 corrcov(sigma_a)
```

I compared the results and both corrcov(sigma_a) and rho produced the same correlation matrix. 
 However then I wanted to change all of the pairwise correlations by exactly +0.1. Which I did, with

```
rho_u = (rho + .1) - .1*eye(10);
```

And I got the following correlation matrix...

```
  1.0000    0.3365    0.4388    0.4396    0.5050    0.4772    0.4897    0.4899    0.4686    0.2556
  0.3365    1.0000    0.3812    0.4656    0.3437    0.4274    0.4658    0.3631    0.4377    0.2638
  0.4388    0.3812    1.0000    0.5027    0.5141    0.4792    0.5199    0.5133    0.5382    0.2985
  0.4396    0.4656    0.5027    1.0000    0.4809    0.5638    0.7221    0.5246    0.5728    0.3295
  0.5050    0.3437    0.5141    0.4809    1.0000    0.4681    0.5366    0.5732    0.5068    0.2948
  0.4772    0.4274    0.4792    0.5638    0.4681    1.0000    0.6093    0.6499    0.5707    0.2813
  0.4897    0.4658    0.5199    0.7221    0.5366    0.6093    1.0000    0.5797    0.6428    0.3079
  0.4899    0.3631    0.5133    0.5246    0.5732    0.6499    0.5797    1.0000    0.5936    0.2971
  0.4686    0.4377    0.5382    0.5728    0.5068    0.5707    0.6428    0.5936    1.0000    0.3435
  0.2556    0.2638    0.2985    0.3295    0.2948    0.2813    0.3079    0.2971    0.3435    1.0000
```

However, when I attempt to take the adjusted correlation matrix and make it a co-variance matrix the cov() is not producing the right matrix. I tried...

```
b = cov(rho_u);
```

Why is that? Is there another way to do that? Or is there a way to adjust what I did with

```
 rho = inv(sqrt(diag(diag(sigma_a))))*sigma_a*inv(sqrt(diag(diag(sigma_a))));
```

so that it does the opposite (rho found the correlation matrix) to get the co-varience matrix instead?

Based on my understanding from the answer below, then the co-variance matrix for rho_u would be achieved by, doing...

```
sigma = sqrt(var(rho_u));
D = diag(sigma); 
sigma_u = D*rho_u*D
```

Is this what was meant? I was little confused by which variables I should take the variance to. I thought that meant rho_u?

Comment: Consider marking the answers as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/)  that solve your previous problems in your previous questions by clicking *`✔`* on the left of the answers. You can also [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/) all the helpful answers by clicking *`▲`* on the left of the answers. This awards the volunteers the reward that they deserve and helps the future visitors to identify the usefulness of the answers. If those answers don't solve your problem, please comment under the answers to explain the problem/s to let the answerers know about that. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The MATLAB function `cov` is not defined to transform a correlation matrix to covariance matrix, as its documentation says

> ```
> cov(X), if X is a vector, returns the variance.  For matrices, where 
> each row is an observation, and each column a variable, cov(X) is the 
> covariance matrix.
> ```

So simply feeding the correlation matrix to `cov()` won't work. What you need to calculate the covariance matrix is the variance of your variables (which you can calculate from your data, but didn't post here)

So in your example using the `10x10` correlation matrix `rho` you posted and using some random numbers for the the standard deviations

```
sigma = rand(size(rho(:,1)));
D = diag(sigma);         % Make the sigmas appear on the diagonal of an 10x10 matrix
```

(you have to insert the calculated values from your input data, of course). You can then calculate the covariance matrix by

```
S = D*rho*D
```